# Local minimum for squared slack variable method

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to show that if $(x^*,y^*)$ is a local minimum for

$
\min_{x,y} f(x) \\
s.t. \; c(x) = y^2
$

then $x^*$ is a local minimum for

$
\min_{x} f(x) \\
s.t. \; c(x) \geq 0
$

If we consider globally optimal solutions then the result is easy to see:

$c(x)\geq0 \Rightarrow \exists y : (x,y)\in\{c(x)=y^2\} \Rightarrow f(x^*)\leq f(x)$

However, for some reason I haven't managed to show the corresponding result for local minima. Intuitively, for small enough $\varepsilon$ one should have

$x \in \{x:c(x)\geq0\}\cap B_{\varepsilon}(x^*) \Rightarrow \exists y : (x,y)\in\{(x,y) : c(x)=y^2\} \cap B_{\delta}(x^{*},y^*) \Rightarrow f(x^*)\leq f(x)$,

where the $B$:s are norm balls, but I haven't been able to prove the first implication here. Any ideas?

Comment: First note that $c$ must be continuous. Then use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity to relate a change in $x$ to a change in $y$.

Comment: Ah, of course! The continuity of c ensures that $|c(x)-c(x^*)|=|y^2-y^*2|$ can be made arbitrary small. I'll have to think a little to get the details straight, but thanks a lot!